# Merge [pascal-case] with [pascalcasing]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Could we merge tag [pascal-case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pascal-case) with [pascalcasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pascalcasing)?

Comment: I see that [tag:camelcase] is a synonym of [tag:camelcasing], so having [tag:pascalcasing] makes sense as the root tag. My only question is whether it makes sense to keep these tags at all? Can you be an expert of [tag:pascalcasing]?

Comment: @Kevin, I believe you can, thinking of regex e.g. More than of [tag:acronym], [tag:abbreviation], [tag:shorthand] and similar, I'd say.

Comment: @KevinBrown the "be an expert in" definition of a tag isn't how tags are looked at. There can be contextual tags as well. If they help to organize/sort questions, then they are useful.

Comment: Contextual tags make sense for [tag:string], [tag:array], etc. Allowing you to filter down questions to see if they involve strings, or arrays, or... pascal casing? I see a mix of [tag:naming-conventions] and [tag:case-conversion] questions, and I can't see how [tag:pascalcasing] helps organize them.